# Anybody know a simple base64 conversion site?

Tags: css, base64

I need to convert some images to base64 for embedding into my CSS... anyone know a simple site that will allow me to simply enter a URI and have it convert so I can copy-paste into my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, funny that you answered a question of mine and now I can answer yours. :-)

I am sure there are many other sites that can do this, but I like to use:

http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64

It is reeeeealy simple. You enter the URI of the image you want to convert and it displays the converted code into the box, ready to be copy-pasted into your CSS!

I use it all the time.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Comment: Doesn't let you enter a URL does it?

Comment: You can click brose, and then enter url into pop-up file picker field. That all.

Comment: But you can insert url to it either. Just try.

Comment: @Martin Smith Nothing worry. I myself learned about this about month ago ;)